# Create html Block with js in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I made a function that normally create html blocks for each data that i have in the Array but it does not work.
Can someone help me please .

This is the function :

```
makeGrid (){

    var data = test.map( x => [ x.name, x.price, ] );

    data.forEach(function(element) {
        var elem = () => ({
            type: 'div',
            props: {
                className: 'box',
                children: [{
                    type: 'i',
                    props: {
                        className: 'hvhv'
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'h3',
                    props: {
                        children: element[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'p',
                    props: {
                        children: element[1]
                    }
                }]
                }
        });

        return elem;
    });

}
```

And here i executed the function :

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className = "Grid" >
        < section className = "boxes" >

        <h1> {this.makeGrid()} </h1>

        < /section> < /div > );
  }
}

export default Grid;
```

I want the blocks to be like :

```
    < div className = "box" >
    < i className = "fas fa-chart-pie fa-4x" > < /i>
    <h3 > Analytics < /h3 >
    <p > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.Quasi, expedita ? < /p > < /div >
```

Comment: Where is `test` defined? Is it within the scope of `madeGrid`? Trying doing `console.log(test)` as the first line of `makeGrid` and see if there's anything there.

Comment: import test from "../product.json";          It's defined and there is data but i don't know why the script does not work

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `return` to `forEach`

```
makeGrid (){

var data = test.map( x => [ x.name, x.price, ] );

return data.forEach(function(element) {
    var elem = () => ({
        type: 'div',
        props: {
            className: 'box',
            children: [{
                type: 'i',
                props: {
                    className: 'hvhv'
                }
            }, {
                type: 'h3',
                props: {
                    children: element[0]
                }
            }, {
                type: 'p',
                props: {
                    children: element[1]
                }
            }]
            }
    });

    return elem;
});

 }
```